# How to create "enterprise project" in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to create an "Enterprise" project in DevOps, but I cannot see such option in my DevOps org, just Public and Private.

[DevOps Enterprise Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LBf9.png)

What should I change in the settings?

Nothing in the doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-azdo#create-a-git-repo-in-azure-devops

I tried different setting in Billing section

Answer (score 0):

You generally can see the "**`Enterprise`**" option when you try to create new projects only within the enterprise-level organizations.

An enterprise-level organization normally should:

- have connected to an AAD (Microsoft Entra ID) of an enterprise/company.
- owned and managed by the members of the enterprise/company.

The following organizations cannot see the "**`Enterprise`**" option when creating new projects:

1. The organization that does not connect to any AAD. This type of organizations generally is created and owned by the personal accounts that do not belong to any enterprise/company.
2. The organization that has connected to an AAD, but the organization and AAD are created and owned by the personal accounts.
3. In the AAD of an enterprise/company, the admins might configure some policy rules that only allow particular AAD members can create Enterprise type projects. With the policy rules, in the enterprise-level organization, the users who are not in the allow-list also might not see the "**`Enterprise`**" option when creating new projects within the enterprise-level organizations.